# Get string with multiple parameters in api controller and parse it

Tags: c#, parsing, controller, get

This method accepts this type of uri:

```
/method?a=1&b=2&c=3

[Route("method")]
public string Get(string a, string b, string c)
{
return "ok";
}
```

But if I change uri to something different
let' say `/method?a=1&b=2`
then the method won't work.

How can I write controller action in the way that it will GET any type of string after "?" sign and then parse it as components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass default values to the parameter

```
/method?a=1&b=2&c=3

[Route("method")]
public string Get(string a= "", string b = "", string c = "")
{
return "ok";
}
```

Now it will work for

```
/method
/method?a=1
/method?b=2
/method?c=3
```

and all combinations

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a optional parameter like

```
[Route("method")]
public string Get(string a, string b, string c = "")
{
  return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem has been solved in some releases of MVC4 and you should define the default value for the parameters like below:

```
[Route("method")]
public string Get(string a = "", string b = "", string c = "")
{
    return "ok";
}
```